# how to overcome spark "cannot parse master URL" error?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following simple code in IntelliJ IDEA on my Mac:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf


object SparkGrep {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (args.length < 3) {
      System.err.println("Usage: SparkGrep <host> <input_file> <match_term>")
      System.exit(1)
    }
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkGrep").setMaster(args(0))
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val inputFile = sc.textFile(args(1), 2).cache()
    val matchTerm : String = args(2)
    val numMatches = inputFile.filter(line => line.contains(matchTerm)).count()
    println("%s lines in %s contain %s".format(numMatches, args(1), matchTerm))
    System.exit(0)
  }
}
```

In my run configuration, I have added the following program arguments:

```
local[*] src/SparkGrep.scala val
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: 'local[*]'
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:1304)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:199)
    at spark.SparkTest.SparkGrep$.main(SparkGrep.scala:26)
    at spark.SparkTest.SparkGrep.main(SparkGrep.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

What can I do to overcome this error?

Comment: what is `local[*]` ? just specify your loopback `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I did, but the errir simply changed to:  Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: '127.0.0.1'

Comment: The error now says:  invalid master URL

Comment: just so that i understand this correctly you don't have a spark instance (local/grid) already running. You want to instantiate an instance everytime you run this module ? Invalid master indicates there is nothing listening on 7077

Comment: this is just my very first attempt at spark, so I would be OK with a local instance being instantiated - just wanted to se this code run without errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114258/discussion-between-prateek05-and-eugene-goldberg).

Comment: Your code actually works perfectly for me (with first argument `local[*]`) - which Spark version are you using? Looks like the asterisk option was added a while ago (v1.1) - are you using v1.0 by any chance? Either way, you can try `local[2]` or just `local`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## InetlliJ IDEA + MAC + SPARK

After ever step let intelliJ be ready since pulls from maven can be slow sometime

#### IntelliJ Setup

1. Install Scala plugin from `Preferences > Plugins > Scala`
2. `File > New > Project`, Select `Scala` on the left pane, select `SBT` on the right pane
3. Right click on the projects name > `Open Module Settings` > `Libraries`
4. Press the `+` module icon > `Maven` > `org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:1.6.1` > `Enter`
5. Add the library to the `project name`
6. The Spark Library should appear under the External Library section
7. New `scala file` in `src/main/scala` *E.g. Test.scala*

#### Test.scala

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext,SparkConf}

object Test {
 def main(args: Array[String]){
 val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DevDemo").setMaster("local")
 val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
 val inputFile = sc.textFile("/var/log/fsck_hfs.log").cache()
// Creates a DataFrame having a single column named "line"
 val errAs = inputFile.filter(line => line.contains("ERROR"))
 println("Error count : %s".format(errAs.count()))
 }
}
```

#### IntelliJ

`Run Menu` > `Run`

Result: *<<<< Snipped*

```
16/06/13 14:39:19 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (count at Test.scala:14) finished in 1.258 s
16/06/13 14:39:19 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/06/13 14:39:19 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: count at Test.scala:14, took 1.829030 s
Error count : 18
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try following line

val sc = new SparkContext(conf=conf)