# How to run Spark on mesos in standalone mode

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I have installed mesos on my local and configured it as mentioned in the mesos setup. Now I want to run spark on mesos installed on my local machine. I have configured spark according to the official documentation and have running single node hadoop cluster on my local machine. Spark binary package is copied to hdfs root directory and I have set the following properties in spark-env.sh:

```
export MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libmesos.so
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI=hdfs://spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
```

and is spark-defaults.conf :

```
spark.executor.uri         hdfs://spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
```

and running spark with:

```
/bin/spark-shell --master mesos://host:5050
```

is giving the following error:

```
ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: 'mesos://host:5050'
```

Please guide me what I am doing wrong and how to correct it.

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41968724/1387612)?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have tried the mentioned solution but it still doesn't work. It is giving following error: 

ERROR MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Mesos error: Failed to create a master detector for 'host:5050': Failed to parse 'host:5050'

Exception in thread "MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend-mesos-driver" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exiting due to error from cluster scheduler: Failed to create a master detector for 'host:5050': Failed to parse 'host:5050'

Comment: Can you connect from spark host? try `nc host 5050 < /dev/null`

Comment: while trying "nc host 5050 < /dev/null" I am gettng this error:

nc: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Comment: Can you use IP instead. Maybe it's a problem with DNS?

Comment: I have made it working. Now I am able to run spark shell on Mesos. But when running from IDE-Intellij sbt I am not able to connect to mesos. Here is what I am trying :
 `val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("mesos://127.0.0.1:5050").appName("my-app").getOrCreate()`
In build.sbt:
`val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql"% sparkVersion
)`error:
`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: 'mesos://127.0.0.1:5050'`

Comment: Have you tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37796968/1387612)? Please, edit your question with the steps you performed and log with full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully installed Apache Spark on Mesos. Please follow the below steps on your Ubuntu machine.

```
# Update the packages.
$ sudo apt-get update

# Install a few utility tools.
$ sudo apt-get install -y tar wget git

# Install the latest OpenJDK.
$ sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk

# Install autotools (Only necessary if building from git repository).
$ sudo apt-get install -y autoconf libtool

# Install other Mesos dependencies.
$ sudo apt-get -y install build-essential python-dev python-six python-virtualenv libcurl4-nss-dev libsasl2-dev libsasl2-modules maven libapr1-dev libsvn-dev

# Change working directory.
$ cd mesos

#If getting error "libz is required to build mesos"
$sudo apt install zlib1g-dev

# Configure and build.
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
build$../configure
$ make
$ make check
$ make install

$ cd build
#start master
./bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=127.0.0.1 --work_dir=/tmp/mesos
#start slave
./bin/mesos-slave.sh --master=127.0.0.1:5050 --work_dir=/tmp/mesos 

#If facing permission issue
./bin/mesos-slave.sh --master=127.0.0.1:5050 --work_dir=/tmp/mesos --no-systemd_enable_support

#Configuring Spark with Mesos

build spark with mesos support
./build/mvn -Pmesos -DskipTests clean package

In spark-env.sh
export MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY= /usr/local/lib/libmesos.so
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI=/localpath/to/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz

In spark-defaults.conf
spark.executor.uri         /localpath/to/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz

run spark shell
./bin/spark-shell --master mesos://127.0.0.1:5050

#Mesos UI
http://127.0.0.1:5050
```